# Clipping plot axes in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

i wanted to clip / chop / customize (not sure about the exact word choice) a plot.
i'll clarify more details about what i mean. let's say i have a scatter plot taking variables [0,1] on x axis , and it takes two sets or values on y axis, a set ranging from [10,20] and a set ranging from [90,100]. what i want to achieve is to shrink the gap between two sets of points. 
i didn't know what to call this process, so it could be helpful if anyone could point me a duplicate of my question or answer otherwise. 
what are my options? can i scale the gap so it takes less space or can i completely delete it? 
EDIT : thanks for answering about 'axes break'. does anyone have any idea about scaling the axes? for example is [0,10] and [90,100] take 1 cm of length in a plot , is it possible to make [20,90] take another 1 cm?

Comment: Something like [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/broken_axis.html)?

Comment: yeah, thanks , that's what i meant. it seems too complicated though. post it as answer.